# Navigating between the different Stack Exchange sites quickly

Tags: support, navigation

I belong to several Stack Exchange Sites. They are linked by a common email address, but it is difficult to quickly navigate between them.

Am I missing something or would it be possible to have a drop down list that allowed you to quickly move between the different Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow sites?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can quickly access sites you already have accounts on through your profile page.. like this..[image]

Answer (score 13):

Such a feature is already available here. Just click *StackExchange* at the top left in the top bar, and click on *all sites*. You will get the list of all sites ordered by your reputation on those sites.

[image]

Comment: I always forget how ugly the scrollbars were in the XP Luna theme. I mean, why in the world were they *blue*? What designer thought making a fundamental UI element a distinctive, uncustomizable color was a good idea?

Comment: @CodyGray - Because http://ux.stackexchange.com/ was not available at that time ;-)

Comment: Let me know when you figure out an answer for the abomination that is Visual Studio post-2010.

Comment: @CodyGray - Not sure about that. But I am sure that the theme is too much elder than UX.SE :)